# Suspicious program info in nethogs

Tags: networking, ip, port

when i run `nethogs` along with other normal program I see this line, sometimes there are three or four lines with different ports but the same ip in each of them.

```
  PID    USER        PROGRAM                                DEV    SENT        RECIEVED
   ?     root     192.168.0.101:43768-103.231.161.73:80           0.000       0.000 KB/sec
```

Is it normal? I think it has to be something with my ISP. Is it so? or anything wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't worry just yet, it might be just dangling old connections which the kernel hasn't yet terminated by timeout.

Run `sudo netstat -4n -eep` and you'll see lots of connections with the `TIME_WAIT` state and no processes attached to them.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank you. This might be a dumb question but do these ports and openings have nothing to do with backdoors? I mean how can i be sure these ports are not being used by anything malicious.

Comment: @f4him does ["K S Network" from Dhaka](https://whois.domaintools.com/103.231.161.73) mean anything to you?

Comment: You can't be sure but nethogs and netstat alone won't help you find out. To be honest Linux is severely lacking in utilities which can deeply scan the workings of your kernel and then given the Linux kernel open architecture it's quite easy to modify the kernel on the fly, so that you won't be able to detect anything. And then there is UEFI malware in the wild, so it gets even more complicated.

Comment: @muru I looked up the ip also, and found the same info, thats why I was asking this question. I live in Comilla it's a district of Bangladesh) and Dhaka is the capital of our country. That's why I was also reffering the issue of being something with my ISP. I think I have to ask my ISP regarding the IP.